# Python Returning Types Translated to C++

Tags: python, c++, code-translation

I inherited a bit of code in Python to convert to C++. The Python code throws an exception based on a error code returned by other functions. The Python code uses a utility function called `errors(...)` that contains creates a dictionary to map error codes to exceptions. It that returns the type of the exception and the calling code instantiates it with its own message.

```
class BaseError(Exception):
    pass

class Error1(BaseError):
    pass

class Error2(BaseError):
    pass

def errors(code):
    errors_ = {
        1: BaseError,
        2: Error1,
        3: Error2
    }

    try:
        return errors_[code]
    except KeyError:
        return errors_[1]

def ReturnAnError():
    # Oops an error!
    return 2

try:
    val = ReturnAnError()
    if(val):
        raise errors(val)('{} Failed'.format("Example Failed"))
except BaseError as ex:
    print(ex)
```

My initial thought is to take an easy path and redefine the Python `errors(code)` function as  `void errors(uint8_t code, const char * msg)` in c++ and then  make a select statement that will throw the exception itself.

Is there a more elegant or concise solution to translate this code directly? In particular, what is the most direct translation of `raise errors(val)('{} Failed'.format("Example Failed"))` in c++?

Comment: May you can `throw` an exception in `errors` instead of `return` an object from `errors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I directly translate your code in C++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class BaseError {
  public:
    BaseError(std::string s) : msg(s) {}
    virtual ~BaseError() {} // useless because inherited classes do not have attribute to delete
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const BaseError & e) {
       out << e.msg;
       return out;
    }
    static BaseError * mk(std::string s) { return new BaseError(s); }
  private:
    std::string msg;
};

class Error1 : public BaseError {
  public:
    Error1(std::string s) : BaseError(s) {}
    static BaseError * mk(std::string s) { return new Error1(s); }
};

class Error2 : public Error1 {
  public:
    Error2(std::string s) : Error1(s) {}
    static BaseError * mk(std::string s) { return new Error2(s); }
};

typedef BaseError * (*fmk)(std::string);

fmk errors(int code) 
{
  const static std::map<int, fmk> error = {
       {1, &BaseError::mk},
       {2, &Error1::mk},
       {3, &Error2::mk}
  };
  std::map<int, fmk>::const_iterator it = error.find(code);
  
  return ((it == error.end()) ? error.find(1) : it)->second;
}

int ReturnAnError()
{
  // Oops an error!
  return 2;
}


int main()
{
  try {
    int val = ReturnAnError();
  
    if (val)
      throw (errors(val))("blah blah");
  }
  catch (BaseError * ex) {
      std::cout << *ex << std::endl;
      delete ex;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ c0.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
blah blah
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

About the function *errors* :

- The Python dictionary can be translated to C++ `std::map`
- As I know contrarily to Python I cannot put in the `std::map` the address of the constructor of each class, this is why I used a *static* operation *mk* for each class.
- To avoid to create the `std::map` each time *errors* is called I defined *error* `static` (and `const` to clearly indicate I do not want to modify it), but this is an optimization and this is not mandatory.
- In Python the exceptions are very used, this is less the case in C++, this is why I use an iterator to know if the code is a known key, and I test it.

To have a way to print the instances of the classes I overloaded the `operator<<`, anyway that does not allow to check the program created an *Error1*, and even I change the code to have :

```
  try {
    int val = ReturnAnError();
  
    if (val)
      throw (errors(val))("blah blah");
  }
  catch (Error2 * ex) {
      std::cout << "err2" << *ex << std::endl;
      delete ex;
  }
  catch (Error1 * ex) {
      std::cout << "err1" << *ex << std::endl;
      delete ex;
  }
  catch (BaseError * ex) {
      std::cout << *ex << std::endl;
      delete ex;
  }
```

the executed code will be `catch (BaseError * ex) {...}`

If I do :

```
  try {
    int val = ReturnAnError();
  
    if (val)
      throw *(errors(val))("blah blah");
  }
  catch (Error2 & ex) {
      std::cout << "err2" << ex << std::endl;
  }
  catch (Error1 & ex) {
      std::cout << "err1" << ex << std::endl;
  }
  catch (BaseError & ex) {
      std::cout << ex << std::endl;
  }
```

again the executed code will be `catch (BaseError & ex) {...}` (and I created a memory leak).

So a `virtual` operation is needed to differentiate the classes when pritting, for instance :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class BaseError {
  public:
    BaseError(std::string s) : msg(s) {}
    virtual ~BaseError() {} // useless because inherited classes do not have attribute to delete
    virtual void print(std::ostream & out) const { out << msg; }
    static BaseError * mk(std::string s) { return new BaseError(s); }
  private:
    std::string msg;
};

class Error1 : public BaseError {
  public:
    Error1(std::string s) : BaseError(s) {}
    virtual void print(std::ostream & out) const { 
      out << "error1 ";
      BaseError::print(out);
    }
    static BaseError * mk(std::string s) { return new Error1(s); }
};

class Error2 : public Error1 {
  public:
    Error2(std::string s) : Error1(s) {}
    virtual void print(std::ostream & out) const { 
      out << "error2 ";
      BaseError::print(out);
    }
    static BaseError * mk(std::string s) { return new Error2(s); }
};

typedef BaseError * (*fmk)(std::string);

fmk errors(int code) 
{
  const static std::map<int, fmk> error = {
       {1, &BaseError::mk},
       {2, &Error1::mk},
       {3, &Error2::mk}
  };
  std::map<int, fmk>::const_iterator it = error.find(code);
  
  return ((it == error.end()) ? error.find(1) : it)->second;
}

int ReturnAnError()
{
  // Oops an error!
  return 2;
}


int main()
{
  try {
    int val = ReturnAnError();
  
    if (val)
      throw (errors(val))("blah blah");
  }
  catch (BaseError * ex) {
      ex->print(std::cout);
      std::cout << std::endl;
      delete ex;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
error1 blah blah
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

> Is there a more elegant or concise solution

To be frank this is at least not concise, but your Python code is not too ;-)

Comment: It seems not better than just adding the type into `BaseError`.

Comment: @yao99 can you be more explicit, I do understand what you mean and why

Comment: `errors` in the python code can be handled by different catch segment, but the pointer to `BaseError` cannot. And it seems why using `errors` in the Python code.

Comment: @yao99 yes but this is different than the Python code, the same change can be done in Python to simplify, and doing that is incompatible with the title `Python Returning Types Translated to C++`

Answer (score 1):

One function, exactly same name and same types of each param, cannot have two return types. So there is no way allow `errors` return different type of exceptions. i.e. `errors` cannot be exactly translated.

But for `raise errors(val)("...")`, one simple way is `throw` the exception in `errors`. sample code:

```
#include <string>
class BaseError {
public:
    std::string s;
    BaseError(const std::string &_s):s(_s){}
};
class Error1 : public BaseError {
public:
    Error1(const std::string &s):BaseError(s){}
};
class Error2 : public BaseError {
public:
    Error2(const std::string &s):BaseError(s){}
};

void errors(int val, const std::string &s)
{
    switch(val)
    {
    case 1:
        throw BaseError(s);
    case 2:
        throw Error1(s);
    case 3:
        throw Error2(s);
    default:
        throw BaseError(s);
    }
}
```

Or if needed an `object` can `throw` in other where, one way is that creating a `class` can `throw`  exceptions. sample code:

```
class errors {
public:
    int val;
    std::string s;
    errors(int _val, const std::string _s): val(_val), s(_s){}
    void raise()
    {
        switch(val)
        {
        case 1:
            throw BaseError(s);
        case 2:
            throw Error1(s);
        case 3:
            throw Error2(s);
        default:
            throw BaseError(s);
        }
    }
};
```